# Word Count per Surah

Tags: quran, surah

I understand that the Quran's suwar are organized, by general but not precise principle, from longest to shortest. Since the ayat are different sizes across suwar, the number of ayat within any individual surah doesn't accurately convey how long the surah is compared to others. I'd like to get a sense of how long each surah is compared to its neighbors, and word count would more accurately reflect that. (Syllable count would be cool too, but that's more work than necessary for my curiosity.)

Does anyone know where I could find a word count for every individual surah of the Quran? I can find word counts for the whole Quran, concordinances, and such, but I am only interested in word counts for each individual surah.

Comment: "I understand that the Quran's suwar are organized, by general but not precise principle..." that is not correct. And what is your definition of "word" in relevance to Arabic which is the language of the qur'an. And if you got your information what is the benefit?

Comment: "Word" for the sake of practicality is every united clump of letters. I know that Arabic has information-dense words with lots of prefixes and suffixes that group words together. A syllabic count would be great for the sake of purer accuracy, by the matter is largely one of curiosity and it would be more involved to calculate such.
The organization of suwar is usually presented as them being organized (Al-Fatiha excepted) on principle of size. I can't judge the accuracy of such statements by ayat count, and thought that word/word-clump counts would be sufficient.

Comment: Let me explain: For example in the given answer the word count saying al-Fatihah has 29 words: counts the Basmallah "بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم " which are 4 words more than other possible counts. While it also doesn't count the word "و" (and) in "وإيّاك" and "ولا" as a word of it's own. Also be aware that in Arabic "بسم" is counted as two words as the letter "ب" is a distinct letter meaning "with" or "in the".

Comment: :) شكرا! أعرف بعض من اللغة العربية وأفهمها غرضك But I figured that dismantling each cluster of words was too much effort for my mere curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  #  |   Surah Name   | Number of words |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  1  |   Al-Fatihah   |        29       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  2  |   Al-Baqarah   |       6140      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  3  |    Al Imran    |       3501      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  4  |    An-Nisa'    |       3763      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  5  |   Al-Ma'idah   |       2837      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  6  |    Al-An'am    |       3056      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  7  |    Al-A'raf    |       3341      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  8  |    Al-Anfal    |       1242      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  9  |    At-Tawbah   |       2505      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  10 |      Yunus     |       1839      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  11 |       Hud      |       1946      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  12 |      Yusuf     |       1795      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  13 |     Ar-Ra'd    |       853       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  14 |    Ibraheem    |       830       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  15 |     Al-Hijr    |       657       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  16 |     An-Nahl    |       1844      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  17 |     Al-Isra    |       1558      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  18 |     Al-Kahf    |       1583      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  19 |     Maryam     |       971       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  20 |      Ta-Ha     |       1353      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  21 |   Al-Anbiya'   |       1174      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  22 |     Al-Hajj    |       1279      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  23 |  Al-Mu'minoon  |       1052      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  24 |     An-Nur     |       1319      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  25 |    Al-Furqan   |       896       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  26 |  ash-Shu`ara'  |       1320      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  27 |     An-Naml    |       1159      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  28 |    Al-Qasas    |       1438      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  29 |   Al-`Ankabut  |       978       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  30 |     Ar-Rum     |       817       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  31 |     Luqman     |       550       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  32 |    As-Sajdah   |       372       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  33 |    Al-Ahzab    |       1303      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  34 |      Saba'     |       884       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  35 |      Fatir     |       778       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  36 |     Yaseen     |       730       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  37 |    As-Saffat   |       865       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  38 |       Sad      |       735       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  39 |    Az-Zumar    |       1177      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  40 |     Ghafir     |       1226      |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  41 |    Fussilat    |       794       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  42 |    Ash-Shura   |       860       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  43 |   Az-Zukhruf   |       836       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  44 |    Ad-Dukhan   |       346       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  45 |   Al-Jathiyah  |       488       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  46 |    Al-Ahqaf    |       645       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  47 |    Muhammad    |       542       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  48 |     Al-Fath    |       560       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  49 |   Al-Hujurat   |       353       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  50 |       Qaf      |       373       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  51 |   Ad-Dhariyat  |       360       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  52 |     At-Tur     |       312       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  53 |     An-Najm    |       360       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  54 |    Al-Qamar    |       342       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  55 |    Ar-Rahman   |       352       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  56 |   Al-Waqi'ah   |       379       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  57 |    Al-Hadeed   |       575       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  58 |  Al-Mujadilah  |       475       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  59 |    Al-Hashr    |       447       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  60 |  Al-Mumtahanah |       352       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  61 |     As-Saff    |       226       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  62 |   Al-Jumu'ah   |       177       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  63 |  Al-Munafiqun  |       181       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  64 |   At-Taghabun  |       242       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  65 |    At-Talaq    |       289       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  66 |   At-Tahreem   |       254       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  67 |     Al-Mulk    |       333       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  68 |    Al-Qalam    |       301       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  69 |    Al-Haqqah   |       260       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  70 |   Al-Ma'aarij  |       217       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  71 |       Nuh      |       227       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  72 |     Al-Jinn    |       286       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  73 |  Al-Muzzammil  |       200       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  74 |  Al-Muddathir  |       256       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  75 |   Al-Qiyamah   |       164       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  76 |    Al-Insan    |       243       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  77 |   Al-Mursalat  |       181       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  78 |    An-Naba'    |       174       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  79 |   An-Nazi'at   |       179       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  80 |     `Abasa     |       133       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  81 |   At-Takweer   |       104       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  82 |   Al-Infitar   |        81       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  83 | Al-Mutaffifeen |       169       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  84 |   Al-Inshiqaq  |       108       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  85 |    Al-Burooj   |       109       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  86 |    At-Tariq    |        61       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  87 |     Al-A'la    |        72       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  88 |  Al-Ghashiyah  |        92       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  89 |     Al-Fajr    |       139       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  90 |    Al-Balad    |        82       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  91 |    Ash-Shams   |        54       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  92 |     Al-Lail    |        71       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  93 |    Ad-Dhuha    |        40       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  94 |   Al-Inshirah  |        27       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  95 |     Al-Teen    |        34       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  96 |    al-`Alaq    |        72       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  97 |     Al-Qadr    |        30       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  98 |   Al-Bayyinah  |        94       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
|  99 |   Az-Zalzala   |        36       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 100 |    Al-Adiyat   |        40       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 101 |   al-Qari`ah   |        36       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 102 |   At-Takathur  |        28       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 103 |     Al-Asr     |        14       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 104 |   Al-Humazah   |        33       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 105 |     Al-Feel    |        23       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 106 |     Quraish    |        17       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 107 |   Al-Maa'oun   |        25       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 108 |   Al-Kawthar   |        10       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 109 |   Al-Kafiroun  |        27       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 110 |     An-Nasr    |        19       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 111 |    Al-Masad    |        23       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 112 |    Al-Ikhlas   |        15       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 113 |    Al-Falaq    |        23       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
| 114 |     Al-Nas     |        20       |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: This count is based on which qira'a?

Comment: @Medi1Saif It is based on the text on http://tanzil.net/docs/download so I think Hafs.